# The query for the large table is that the clickhouse process is closed

Tags: clickhouse

When you query a large table multiple times, clickhouse process is killed.
The clickhouse version is 1.1.54318.
Two servers were deployed.
The server configuration is as follows: 8C16G200G

The query statement is：

```
SELECT visit_id, carrier, class_name, line_number, uuid, method_name, customer_name, mem_available, region_id, os_id, device_id, app_version_id, threads, file_name, mobile_app_name, cpu, memory, hard_disk, is_symbol, visit_start_time, crash_time from crash
WHERE uuid GLOBAL IN ( SELECT uuid from crash WHERE ch_start_date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND (timestamp >= ? AND timestamp < ?) AND crash_type = ? AND app_id = ? ORDER BY crash_time DESC LIMIT ?, ? ) ORDER BY crash_time DESC
```

There are about 1.6 million data in this crash table.

System logs are as follow：

> Aug 5 09:30:27 clickhouse02 kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 16959 (AsyncBlockInput) score 947 or sacrifice child
>
> Aug 5 09:30:27 clickhouse02 kernel: Killed process 19079 (clickhouse-serv) total-vm:40090428kB, anon-rss:15314964kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
>
> Aug 5 09:30:27 clickhouse02 systemd-logind: New session 4753 of user root.
>
> Aug 5 09:30:29 clickhouse02 systemd: Started Session 4753 of user root.
>
> Aug 5 09:30:29 clickhouse02 systemd: Starting Session 4753 of user root.

If anyone can answer that, thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please clarify what your question is?

Comment: The clickhouse process is killed by the query, but the data file in this table does not exceed the memory limit